# Can't set environment variables with docker run -e or --env-file option

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/server

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json /usr/server/

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/server/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "./bin/www.js" ]`
```

Then I run

```
    docker run -d -p 3000:3000 chatapp-back 
    -e DB_HOST="mongodb://localhost:27017/" 
    -e DB_USER="user" 
    -e DB_NAME="dbname" 
    -e DB_PASS="dbpass" 
    -e JWT_SECRET="my-jwt-secret"
```

Console output with `docker logs <container-id>`

```
[eval]:1
JWT_SECRET=my-jwt-secret
^

ReferenceError: my is not defined
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:122:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:329:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at evalScript (internal/bootstrap/node.js:590:27)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:265:9)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

I also tried with `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 chatapp-back --env-file .env`

but console returned

```
node: bad option: --env-file
```

I'm doing something  wrong here

I used [docker run documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

[this article](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/#the-dot-env-file-env)

[and this article](https://medium.com/@felipedutratine/pass-environment-variables-from-docker-to-my-nodejs-or-golang-app-a1f2ddec31f5)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rearrange the docker run command, as the [default entrypoint](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/f5875531604b4b3b9fbc36437182781c3655c8ae/10/stretch/docker-entrypoint.sh) for node base docker image, is `node`, so the container considers `--env-file .env` as an argument to node process.

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000  --env-file .env chatapp-back
```

Also, you can verify this before running the main process.

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 --env-file .env chatapp-back -e "console.log(process.env)"
```

Comment: ...same for your `docker run -e` options; they need to be _before_ the image name.

Answer (score 2):

Your image name should come **last**. I was doing the same thing at first.

```
     docker run -d -p 3000:3000 
        -e DB_HOST="mongodb://localhost:27017/" 
        -e DB_USER="user" 
        -e DB_NAME="dbname" 
        -e DB_PASS="dbpass" 
        -e JWT_SECRET="my-jwt-secret"
        chatapp-back
```